# How to preserve sourceMappingURL with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

The file I'm uploading contains `//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.map.js` in the last line, but when I check the source code after deployed, everything is minified without this line.

Is there anything I can do to preserve the reference to the source map?

Comment: Firebase Hosting doesn't do anything to change the source of the files that you deploy. It literally zips up the directory you've set as the `public` directory and deploys that to the CDN. Are you sure you source mapping file is being deployed to Firebase Hosting?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks to your comment I could find the real problem.

Comment: That's good to hear on both counts Gustavo. :-) Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Frank's comment, I could look to the right place. Firebase Hosting has nothing to do with the problem.

I'm using webpack and minifying with webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin. `sourceMap` option at UglifyJS should be true by default, but for some reason it only preserved the reference to the source map when I explicitly set the option `sourceMap: true`.